# How to populate the doc with the next row in the sheets data

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs

Helloo, I just started using app script with little to no exp. I have a sheets that has a 23 rows, 4 columns it's set up like

Date/Time In/Time Out/(and then more but I want to get the first 3 columns)

Whenever I run, it only populates the template doc with the first row.
The data is set up like:

| Date | Time in | Time out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01 | 1:00pm | 2:00pm |
| 01/02 | 1:30pm | 2:31pm |
| 01/03 | 1:20pm | 2:12pm |

```
function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('the template');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('temp folder');
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('person');
  const rows = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 24, 6).getValues();
  const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(destinationFolder);
  rows.forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (index === 0) return;
    if (row\[2\] === 0) return;
  if (row\[6\] === 0) return;
  // This is if there is a field trip to check if there are more time ins and time outs

  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  const body = doc.getBody();
  const friendlyDate = new Date(row[0]).toLocaleDateString();


  body.replaceText('{{Date1}}', friendlyDate);
  body.replaceText('{{Date1in}} ', row[1]);
  body.replaceText('{{Date1out}} ', row[2]);

  body.replaceText('{{Date 2}}', friendlyDate);
  body.replaceText('{{Date2in}}', row[1])
  body.replaceText('{{Date2out}}', row[2])

  body.replaceText('{{Date 3}}', friendlyDate);
  body.replaceText('{{Date3in}}', row[1])
  body.replaceText('{{Date3out}}', row[2])

  body.replaceText('{{Date 4}}', friendlyDate);
  body.replaceText('{{Date4in}}', row[1])
  body.replaceText('{{Date4out}}', row[2])

  body.replaceText('{{Date 5}}', friendlyDate);
  body.replaceText('{{Date5in}}', row[1])
  body.replaceText('{{Date5out}}', row[2])
```

I expected it to populate the template for the week and work down but it'll only put that first day instead of moving onto the next day.

Answer (score 1):

You loops are using the same index, try change the approach by iterating differently.

```
function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  const googleDocTemplateId = 'the template'; //template file ID
  const destinationFolderId = 'temp folder'; //destination folder ID
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('person');
  const rows = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 23, 3).getValues();

  rows.forEach(function (row) {
    if (row[1] === 0 || row[2] === 0) return; // Skip rows where either "Time In" or "Time Out" is zero

    const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById(googleDocTemplateId);
    const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(destinationFolder);

    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    const body = doc.getBody();
    const friendlyDate = new Date(row[0]).toLocaleDateString();

    body.replaceText('{{Date}}', friendlyDate);
    body.replaceText('{{TimeIn}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{TimeOut}}', row[2]);
  });
}
```

Comment: It's still using the data of that first row. I apologize, I'm still learning how do I make it use the next line. I was thinking of using .getRange for each row as a new loop, but I don't know how future proof that would be.